# Cannot print stdout from na_ontap_command ansible module

Tags: ansible, netapp

I'm trying to get stdout_lines output from  n[a_ontap_command ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/netapp/ontap/na_ontap_command_module.html#ansible-collections-netapp-ontap-na-ontap-command-module) on NetApp ONTAP9.8P6.

This gives me the complete output:

```
 tasks:
  - name: Version CLI Command
    na_ontap_command:
      command: ['version']
      return_dict: yes
      <<: *login
    register: cluster_version

  - name: Print Output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ cluster_version }}"
```

Output:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": {
            "invoked_command": "version",
            "result_value": 1,
            "status": "passed",
            "stdout": "NetApp Release 9.8P6: Tue Aug 03 16:21:11 UTC 2021\n",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "NetApp Release 9.8P6: Tue Aug 03 16:21:11 UTC 2021"
            ],
            "xml_dict": {
                "active_element": "",
                "cli-output": {
                    "attrs": {},
                    "data": "NetApp Release 9.8P6: Tue Aug 03 16:21:11 UTC 2021\n"
                },
                "cli-result-value": {
                    "attrs": {},
                    "data": "'1'"
                },
                "last_element": "results",
                "results": {
                    "attrs": {
                        "status": "passed",
                        "xmlns": "http://www.netapp.com/filer/admin"
                    },
                    "data": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I just print e.g. stdout or stdout_lines?

I found examples with  msg: "{{ cluster_version.stdout }}" or [looping through results](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-dict-object-has-no-attribute-stdout-or-stderr-how-to-resolve/).

msg: "{{ cluster_version.stdout }}" ends in following error msg:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\
```

And the looping I dont know how to use in my case as the results key-item cannot be found in the output of my playbook.

Maybe someone has experienced this and could help with an idea or solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered variable `cluster_version` contains another dictionary within, i.e. `msg`.

So to get the `stdout` or `stdout_lines`, you need to refer with `cluster_version['msg']`, like below:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: cluster_version['msg']['stdout']
```

Comment: ok: [localhost] => {
    "cluster_version['msg']['stdout_lines']": [
        "NetApp Release 9.8P6: Tue Aug 03 16:21:11 UTC 2021"
    ]
}